# How to make json_encode always return as JSON Array?

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array, slim

this is my code:

```
  $db = connect_mysqli();

  $response = array();

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM questions ORDER BY RAND ()";
  $result = $db->query($sql);

  while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC))
  {
    $response['answers'][$row['id']] = array('question_id'=>$row['id'], 'option_id'=>null);
  }

  echo json_encode($response);
```

And this is the response:

```
{
  answers: {
    1: {
      question_id: "1",
      option_id: null
    },
    2: {
      question_id: "2",
      option_id: null
    },
    3: {
      question_id: "3",
      option_id: null
    },
    4: {
      question_id: "4",
      option_id: null
    }
  }
}
```

How to make the response always return JSON Array? not JSON Object like that. Sometimes the response is return JSON Array and in some part, return JSON Object. I want all response tobe JSON Array.

So, it should be like this:

```
{
  answers: [
    1: {
      question_id: "1",
      option_id: null
    },
    2: {
      question_id: "2",
      option_id: null
    },
    3: {
      question_id: "3",
      option_id: null
    },
    4: {
      question_id: "4",
      option_id: null
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Try change `$response['answers'][$row['id']]` to `$response['answers'][]`

Comment: i need this as a key $response['answers'][$row['id']] @MrHery

Comment: Then try fetch from database as an object, not array.

Comment: If you need the key to be $row['id'], then the json output you got is correct. You cannot have an array that has keys as values in json. If you want to have it return an array then embed the id into the object instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
$response['answers'][$row['id']] = array('question_id'=>$row['id'], 'option_id'=>null);
```

This previous line should be changed to:

```
$response['answers'][] = array('question_id'=>$row['id'], 'option_id'=>null);
```

The problem comes from the fact that you do not start the array at an index of 0.

Comment: I need this $response['answers'][$row['id']] as a key

Comment: If you need a key, it's an object, not a array, you need. Arrays always start from a zero index and go up from there.

Comment: Hmm, then how i can show it? if is an JSON Array answers[1].option_id, how for an JSON Object?

Comment: This is how would access it an object instead of an array: `$answers[1]->option_id`

Comment: In JavaScript accessing an array or an object is the same notation: `answers[1].option_id` should work. See this: https://jsfiddle.net/loic294/u2shu0Ls/

Answer (score 0):

does it help you

```
   $response = json_encode($response);
```

Answer (score 0):

cast the `$row['id']` as string to get desired result.

```
$db = connect_mysqli();

$response = array();

$sql = "SELECT * FROM questions ORDER BY RAND ()";
$result = $db->query($sql);

while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC))
 {
   $response['answers'][(string)$row['id']] = array('question_id'=>$row['id'], 'option_id'=>null);
 }

echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: No, it's still same like before :(

Comment: @DimasAdiAndrea please validate the json you are expecting.